# Passing model and other params to controller in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

OK, I'm new to MVC and I'm working away on an issue which I can't see to find an answer for.

I'm trying to pass my FormModel object and also a rowId to an Action method in my controller using jQuery. The rowId comes through as expected but the FormModel either comes through as null or with all the properties set to their default values.

I believe it's something to do with the MVC 3 binding mechanism, but being so new to MVC I can't be 100% sure.

Here's a very simplified version of the Action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveProductMessage(FormModel form, int rowId)
    {
        try
        {
            if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return Redirect("~/DefaultExceptionPage.htm");
        }

        return PartialView("_ProductMessage", form);
    }
```

and here's the JavaScript that I'm using to try and pass the values through:

```
$(document).ready(
(function () {
    $("#remove-product-message-row").live(
        "click",
        function (rowId) {
            var url = '/Forms/RemoveProductMessage';
            var x = $('#main-form').serialize();
            var dataToSend = { form: JSON.stringify(x), rowId: 1 };

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Forms/RemoveProductMessage",
                type: 'POST',
                data: $.toDictionary(dataToSend),
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#all-product-messages").html(result);
                }
            }); // End of $.ajax call
        });
}));
```

I've tried a few different things and I'm currently trying the jQuery plug-in found here ([jquery.todictionary](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.htmlBflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.StatusInLevel=Active)) but with no luck. I'm not tied to using this plug-in and any other way to get this thing working, I'm open to.

I've tried many various things regarding the $('#main-form').serialize(), but all to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edited to add details**

Ok, I've taken a look in Firebug and the POST for another action method which only takes the FormModel as a param looks like this:

AdministrationFormNumber    5809
BflBaseFormModel.BaseForm...    5809
BflBaseFormModel.BaseForm...    8/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    S_5809DYN_082010
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    S_5809DYN_082010
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    DYN
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    Agent
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    AS
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    GE
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    LM
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    OC
BflBaseFormModel.BflFormB...    Active
BflBaseFormModel.BflOblig...
BflBaseFormModel.BondSubT...
BflBaseFormModel.BondType...    6
BflBaseFormModel.StateNam...    Massachusetts
BflBaseFormModel.Title  Transient/Itinerant Vendor - MA
CreatedDate 3/15/2012 2:39:36 PM
FormNumber  05809
Product.Attachments false
Product.AvailableOnline 
Product.AvailableOnline 
Product.BondAmtMax  0.00
Product.BondAmtMin  0.00
Product.BondAmtStd
Product.BondEffectiveDate
Product.BondExpirationDat...
Product.BondObligationDes...
Product.BondTermMonths
Product.BondType
Product.CancelDays
Product.CategoryId  0
Product.ClassCode
Product.ContactEmail
Product.ContactName 
Product.ContactPhone
Product.ContactUrl
Product.CounterSignatures
Product.Description 
Product.EandOFlag   false
Product.EarliestTermEffec...    1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Product.EndorsementFileNa...
Product.FormId  0
Product.FormTitle
Product.MinCreditScore  0
Product.ObligationType
Product.Obligee.ObligeeNa...
Product.ProductLineId
Product.ProductVersionAva...    1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Product.ProductVersionExp...    1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Product.RateCode
Product.RateType    �
Product.RenewalFileName 
Product.RenewalMethod
Product.RiskType
Product.SpecialInstructio...
Product.State
QiFormModel.Attachment  N
QiFormModel.Description Commonwealth of Massachusettes - Transient/Itinerant Vendor Bond
QiFormModel.DigitalSignat...    False
QiFormModel.EffDateWrappe...    True
QiFormModel.FileName    LMS_15809_082010.xdp
QiFormModel.FormNumber  LMS_15809/ 8/2010
RowID   b6c0c011-6153-4391-be0d-7bb7c106372c
StateOfEntity   Added

However, when I look at the POST for the RemoveProductMessage I see the following:

form    AdministrationFormNumber=5809&FormNumber=05809&RowID=b6c0c011-6153-4391-be0d-7bb7c106372c&CreatedDate=3%2F15%2F2012+2%3A39%3A36+PM&StateOfEntity=Added&BflBaseFormModel.Title=Transient%2FItinerant+Vendor+-+MA&BflBaseFormModel.BaseFormID=5809&BflBaseFormModel.BaseFormRevisionDate=8%2F1%2F2010+12%3A00%3A00+AM&BflBaseFormModel.BondTypeId=6&BflBaseFormModel.BondSubTypeId=&BflBaseFormModel.StateName=Massachusetts&BflBaseFormModel.BflObligeeName=&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.PostedCompanyModels=AS&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.PostedCompanyModels=GE&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.PostedCompanyModels=LM&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.PostedCompanyModels=OC&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.LibraryName=Agent&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.FormFileType=DYN&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.FileName=S_5809DYN_082010&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.StatusInLevel=Active&QiFormModel.FormNumber=LMS_15809%2F+8%2F2010&QiFormModel.Description=Commonwealth+of+Massachusettes+-+Transient%2FItinerant+Vendor+Bond&QiFormModel.DigitalSignatureWrapped=False&QiFormModel.EffDateWrapped=True&QiFormModel.Attachment=N&QiFormModel.FileName=LMS_15809_082010.xdp&BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels%5B0%5D.FileName=S_5809DYN_082010&Product.FormId=0&Product.FormTitle=&Product.AvailableOnline=&Product.EarliestTermEffectiveDate=1%2F1%2F0001+12%3A00%3A00+AM&Product.ProductVersionAvailabilityDate=1%2F1%2F0001+12%3A00%3A00+AM&Product.ProductVersionExpirationDate=1%2F1%2F0001+12%3A00%3A00+AM&Product.Attachments=false&Product.Description=&Product.RiskType=&Product.RateType=%EF%BF%BD&Product.EandOFlag=false&Product.BondEffectiveDate=&Product.BondExpirationDate=&Product.BondTermMonths=&Product.CancelDays=&Product.RenewalFileName=&Product.RenewalMethod=&Product.EndorsementFileName=&Product.BondAmtStd=&Product.BondAmtMin=0.00&Product.BondAmtMax=0.00&Product.MinCreditScore=0&Product.SpecialInstructions=&Product.State=&Product.ProductLineId=&Product.BondType=&Product.CategoryId=0&Product.AvailableOnline=&Product.ClassCode=&Product.RateCode=&Product.CounterSignatures=&Product.BondObligationDescription=&Product.ObligationType=&Product.ContactName=&Product.ContactPhone=&Product.ContactEmail=&Product.ContactUrl=&Product.ProductMessages%5B0%5D.MsgCode=%24+++&Product.ProductMessages%5B0%5D.MessageToAddress=1235&Product.ProductMessages%5B0%5D.StateOfEntity=Added&Product.ProductMessages%5B0%5D.MessageRowID=cae73ecf-4bc9-45f2-bd5d-4040dc7362ef&Product.Obligee.ObligeeName=

It appears that the values are not being correctly set in a Key/Value pairing.

The Model Object:

```
public class FormModel : BaseModel
{
    private ProductModel productModel;

    public BflBaseFormModel BflBaseFormModel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public QiFormModel QiFormModel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Form Number")]
    public string FormNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int AdministrationFormNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public System.Guid RowID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public System.DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [AutoMapper.IgnoreMap]
    public string Information
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [AutoMapper.IgnoreMap]
    public ProductModel Product
    {
        get
        {
            if (productModel == null)
            {
                productModel = new ProductModel();
            }

            return productModel;
        }

        set
        {
            productModel = value;
        }
    }

    public void SetFormModels()
    {
        // Map Companies to BflForms
        foreach (var bflFormByLibraryModels in BflBaseFormModel.BflFormByLibraryModels)
        {
            if (bflFormByLibraryModels.BflFormModels != null)
            {
                bflFormByLibraryModels.BflFormModels.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                bflFormByLibraryModels.BflFormModels = new List<BflFormModel>();
            }

            foreach (var selectedCompany in bflFormByLibraryModels.PostedCompanyModels)
            {
                var bflFormModel = new BflFormModel();
                bflFormModel.CompanyID = selectedCompany;
                bflFormModel.BaseFormID = bflFormByLibraryModels.BaseFormID;
                bflFormModel.BaseFormRevisionDate = bflFormByLibraryModels.BaseFormRevisionDate;
                bflFormModel.LibraryID = bflFormByLibraryModels.LibraryID;
                bflFormByLibraryModels.BflFormModels.Add(bflFormModel);
            }
        }

        // Verify that QILatest has been set correctly
        if (QiFormModel != null && QiFormModel.AdministrationFormNumber == null)
        {
            QiFormModel = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The View is pretty large, made up of various Partial Views so I won't post it on here.

**OK, I've gone done a different path here and got the data across another way, so all is good.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the two parameters with the stringify method, like this

```
var dataToSend = { form: JSON.stringify(x), rowId: JSON.stringify(1) };
```

Comment: Adding the contentType causes the following exception: [ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: form.]

Comment: ok, remove the content type and only add the stringify to the second parameter

Comment: No exception, but the FormModel is still coming through as null. The rowId is OK though.

Comment: Ok, the problem relies on how you're sending the data in the FormModel class add to your question the view and the model, and if it's possible a capture about how the values are sending in the request